Is Rudin's definition of simple connectedness in his RCA equivalent to the usual one?
At the bullet point $10.38$ in his Real and Complex Analysis, Rudin gives a very quick rundown on homotopy and simple connectedness, but the definition he gives is the following:

If [a topological space] $X$ is connected and every closed curve in $X$ is null-homotopic [i.e. homotopic to a point] then $X$ is said to be simply connected.

However most of the time the usual definition of simple connectedness requires path/arcwise connectedness instead of just connectedness. In the context of the book it would not change much at all since this notion is mostly used with open subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ which are connected iff they are path connected, and there's no difference between the common definition and Rudin's, but I was wondering if Rudin's definition might be equivalent in all settings, or at the very least when restricted to metric/normed spaces.
I'm course expecting that it mostly isn't the case, otherwise requiring path connectedness would be redundant and there would surely be a mention of this fact somewhere, but nothing turned up yet I can't really envision any counter-example on my own, so I thought I'd ask here.

It is not equivalent, read about "topologist's sine curve" as a standard counter-example.

@MoisheKohan Oh I suppose that if there's no nontrivial closed curve then the closed curve condition is trivially true... For some reason I wasn't sure if it was simply connected as in Rudin's definition or not.

The topologist's sine curve does contain nonconstant curves. The actual proof amounts to showing that both path-components are homeomorphic to intervals (one closed, one open).

As per usual I always miss the obvious and over-focus on the wrong thing... Thanks to Moishe Kohan for kindly showing me the way.
Consider the topologist's sine curve $A := \{(x,\, \sin(1/x)) \mid x \in (0,1]\} \cup \{(0,0)\} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$.
It is known to be connected and non-path-connected, let's show that it is simply connected in the sense of Rudin (but won't be in the usual sense since it's not path-connected).
To that end, it suffices to prove that there are no nontrivial loops/closed curves in $A$, i.e. all loops can be reparametrised to be the union of a curve $\gamma_0 : [0,1] \to A$ and its opposite $\check\gamma_0 : t \mapsto \gamma(1-t)$ ("trivial loop" might have another meaning, so I just wanted to define what I had in mind precisely), and check that these types of loops are null-homotopic, hence all loops in $A$ are null-homotopic.
Consider a loop $\gamma : [0,1] \to A$, and write $\gamma(t) =: (x(t), f(x(t))$. The function $x$ is continuous because $\gamma$ and the projection along the first coordinate are, thus $x([0,1]) = [a,b] \subset [0,1]$.
Up to a reparametrisation, we can assume WLOG that $x(0) = x(1) = a$. Let $t_0 \in (0,1)$ be such that $x(t_0) = b$.
Then, because $A$ is a functional set, and because we must have $x([0,t_0]) = x([t_0,1]) = [a,b]$, we get:
$$\left(\gamma|_{[0, t_0]}\right)^* = \left(\gamma|_{[t_0, 1]}\right)^* = \gamma^*$$
Therefore all loops in $A$ are trivial in the sense I described above.
Now, take a trivial loop $\gamma_0 : [0,1] \to X$ for $X$ any topological space. Up to a reparametrisation, we can assume that: $$\forall t \in \left[0, \frac{1}{2}\right],\quad \gamma_0\left(t\right) = \gamma_0\left(1-t\right)$$
Then we can set:
$$H : (s,r) \in [0,1]^2 \longmapsto \gamma_0\left((1-r)s + r \frac{1}{2}\right)$$
which is well-defined because $(1-r)s + r \frac{1}{2} \in [0,1]$, continuous because $\gamma_0$ and $(s,r) \mapsto (1-r)s + r \frac{1}{2}$ are continuous, and satisfies:
$$\begin{cases} H(s, 0) = \gamma_0(s)\\
H(s, 1) = \gamma_0\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\\
H(1, r) = \gamma_0\left((1-r) + r \frac{1}{2}\right) = \gamma_0\left(1 - r \frac{1}{2}\right) = \gamma_0\left(r \frac{1}{2}\right) = H(0,r)\end{cases}$$
$\gamma_0$ is therefore homotopic to $\gamma_0(1/2)$, and all trivial loops are null-homotopic (reparametrisations should be homotopic to each other right? I guess that's the only point I'd be unclear about right now), and we are done.
